LM393 Comparator - Unusual connection
I have found the following circuit in a schematic of an (old) product from my employer. It shows the connection of the second comparator in the LM393 package which is unused.

The IC is supplied with WGND (negative supply) and WPOS (some positive supply voltage).
Question: What type of problem could arise from this circuit? (Doesn't this configuration lead to constant oscillation at the output, leading to increased current consumption or even damage?)

Why do you think it would lead to oscillation? IMO it should enter one of two stable operation states (depending on input offset), none of which are harmful.

@tobalt there is no input difference and op-amp input offset can be near zero. And there are other reasons why they should not be tied directly to same voltage or directly to ground.

@Justme even when the nominal input offset voltage happens to be ~zero by chance, you would need an induced voltage of several µV (across a sub-mm short) to swing the state notably towards one saturation. I agree tying to the same potential is not good for op-amps where funny things can happen when driven to saturation. For open-drain comparators, I see no real issue. PS: I also agree, that the presented schematic is by no means ideal or universally safe.

There's a subtle possibility- there are shared components between comparators (the current sources) and it's possible that variations in one would slightly (microvolts) affect the others. That effect is measurable and I've measured it in the cousin chip design. So it's slightly better to have a define state on all outputs. However it would be extremely unusual for a sloppy comparator like the LM393 to be used in an application where microvolts mattered, and in any case the comparators will always perform within their loose specifications.

The LM393 was originally produced by National Semiconductor, which was later acquired by Texas Instruments about ten or fifteen years ago. Hence, let's turn to the current TI datasheet for advice on what to do with unused comparators.
In section 7.4 Device Functional Modes, we find this:

All pins of any unused comparators should be tied to
the negative supply.

So, provided WGND is also the negative supply of the quad comparator, the connection scheme is exactly in accordance with the manufacturer's recommendations and no problems will result.
If, however, WGND is not the same as the negative supply, then problems could occur. If WGND is more positive than the negative supply then current could flow because the open collector output happens to be driven low due to the polarity of Vos (50% chance). That could be destructive, and would waste power.

If WGND is more negative than the negative supply by more than a few hundred mV then current would flow through the internal isolation junctions (which are not shown on the simplified schematic) and that could be be destructive.

Specifically, this is true for the TI LM393-N. It might not be true for the non-N version TI LM393, as suggested by TI appnote "snoaa35e.pdf".

@Justme The exact same advice is given in the 2002 LM393 NS datasheet on page 8. Also in the 1982 ND databook (I have only a paper copy). I submit that the 100nA typical output leakage  current is not a sensible concern with a power hungry (1mA/amplifier) bipolar chip and that if one's layout is so execrable that there are diode drops (>300mV) appearing randomly between directly connected IC pins then many other bad things are likely to happen.

Also note that the LM393 is not a power comparator, in fact the outputs are rather wimpy (a few mA max) so it's not like an output will be switching a relay or other nasty load.

LM393 output pin can have two states:

pulls to GND (in your case, WGND)
open-circuit

So if its DC supply is WPOS and WGND, a grounded output pin carries no current in either state.
It is probably safe to tie an unused comparator's input pins to its negative DC supply...certainly safer than leaving them open. The other possibility is to tie both input pins to WPOS. Doing this shuts down more internal current sources, and may very slightly reduce quiescent current into WPOS. However, printed circuit layout may be a bit more difficult than a link between pins 2,3,4.
Having both inputs at equal voltage does mean that some internal nodes operate in their linear region. I would expect that the common WGND connection between pins 2,3,4 would be extremely short, so that no ground loops exist: this shouldn't cause problems.

"Propably safe" - according to TI appnote, it isn't safe to tie inputs together, or to GND or other low impedance node directly. Grounded output will have leakage current from WPOS supply. I think all methods suggested here are not recommended by TI appnote for LM393.

As Spehro says. unused inputs go to negative supply (WGND). A footnote on that same datasheet says, "The input common-mode voltage or either input signal voltage should not be allowed to go negative by more than 0.3V. The upper end
of the common-mode voltage range is V+−1.5 V at 25°C, but either or both inputs can go to 36 V without damage, independent of the magnitude of V+." I imagine that the output leakage current you refer to is insignificant, although an open-circuit output pin current is guaranteed to be zero. Active substrate junctions could destroy both comparators.

I do not deny that. I am simply pointing out that LM393 from NS and LM393-N from TI may work like you say, but LM393 from TI may be a different/newer design and it has a separate appnote what's best or acceptable.

@Justme The LM393 (not N) recommendations are unchanged in the datasheets from 1982 to present.

@SpehroPefhany The TI LM393 (not N) data sheet (SLCS005AF) has no mention what to do with unused pins. The website links to the appnote what to do with unused pins. Can you link to a data sheet?

Just the NS 2002 LM393 datasheet. Also Motorola LM393/LM393A "It is good design practice to ground all unused pins" from here. OP does not specify the maker.

Many types of problems can potentially happen. The circuit you have now is potentially harmful and one of the worst possible ways to leave it unused. The real question is, how relevant are these problems to your circuit. It is possible none of the worst case scenarios never happen in your circuit.
The first thing is that it does not matter if a comparator is used or not, the inputs should not be connected directly to ground or any other low impedance node. Current limit resistors should always be used to limit current below 10mA.
The inputs should also not be connected directly to same voltage with no input voltage difference. It would be acceptable to use e.g. 10k and 10M resistors to ground to guarantee voltage difference.
Unused comparators should be connected so that they do not damage or cause problems to the other comparators.
Inputs should be in normal operation range via resistors, not directly to low impedance nodes. If a method is good or poor depends also on the supply voltage.
Unused outputs should also be left floating. While the output can be grounded, there may be excess leakage current.
TI has an appnote "snoaa35e.pdf" which talks about usage of comparators.
